# What should I do to wrap text in this span?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

What should I do to wrap the text in this span?
That's how it's showing:

[image]

```css
.combobox {
  background-color: red;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 col-md-10">
    <md-autocomplete md-search-text="searchText" md-items="item in querySearch(searchText)" md-item-text="item.DescricaoComSigla">
      <md-item-template>
        <span class="combobox">{{item.DescricaoComSigla}}</span>
      </md-item-template>
    </md-autocomplete>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Post a [mcve] please. Also, are you using Bootstrap?

Comment: @j08691 I edited the html code to show more all the code. And I edited the title to show that I'm using angularjs and angular material.

Comment: Don't put what should be tags in your title, put them in the tags

Comment: @j08691 I did it